# How to call function declared in $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, onload

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refresh = function() {
        alert('doing!');
    }
}
```

How to call `refresh()` function outside the `$(document).ready()`? Anywhere in the jQuery functions?

eg.

```
$('#el').click() {
    document.ready().refresh();
}
```

Comment: `document.ready().refresh();` doesn't make sense, what do you want to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a way to call a method defined in a more local scope from another, you have to either store a reference to it, or declare it at/in a higher scope, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.refresh = function() {
    alert('doing!');
  };
});
```

Or:

```
var refresh = function() {
  alert('doing!');
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  //other code...
});
```